# How can I test that a Tornado handler invokes another API correctly?

Tags: python, tornado

My Tornado application has a handler which invokes another external API using `AsyncHTTPClient` and then returns.

How can I write a unit test which tests that my handler invokes the external API correctly?

I feel like I should run a 2nd server in my unit test which mocks the external server and provides the same API that my handler is hitting. I can provide the URI to hit as a parameter to my application, so it's not hardcoded. However I'm not sure how I'd pull off 2 servers (correctly) in a `AsyncHTTPTestCase`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to test whether `AsyncHTTPClient` works as it's supposed to? I would expect that is already covered by Tornado's unit tests. If you want to test whether your call succeeds, you can't really; even if you have a test service and you test calling it, it is in no way related how an actual service works (to put it differently: your tests may pass, but the real service might be down). You should focus on testing the functionality you introduce, e.g. processing of a service's response (which can be mocked), rather than trying to cover what you don't control.

Comment: @BerislavLopac thanks for the comment. I'm not trying to test `AsyncHTTPClient` but rather test that my handler is creating the correct body, calling the external API correctly, and handling the response correctly.  Right, I don't control the external API, but I have control over how I interact with it, and that's what I'm trying to test.

Comment: I see your point. However it seems like three separate responsibilities, which should ideally be in separate methods. Test the body creation and response handler ones.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing for the meantime. It's not a full end-to-end test, and perhaps that's not even possible without hitting the actual external API, but at least there's less wiggle room for errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of opinions on how to break up and properly handle testing. For a scenario where I am testing things that have to talk to a 3rd party, in your example I would break it into 3 parts a very thin part that just talks to the API. I would then write an integration test to test the part that talks to the API. Then I would make a mock or other test fixture that can replace the call to the API and write the code that processes the API call. That can easily be placed in a unit test, since it will typically be something like:

```
my_new_data = do_process(call_my_third_party_api())
```

You can easily write a test for do_process by just passing in a mock of the data returned by the third party api call.

Then when it's time to test your handler, you just mock out your api call with something that returns the results you expect to get from the third party.

Now you have three distinct tests that test each area of your application. A test you can run to ensure that your code is accessing the API correctly. A test that tells you if you are handling the processing of the API correctly and a third test that tells whether you are returning that information properly to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mock library (unittest.mock in python3.5):

```
import unittest
from cStringIO import StringIO

from mock import patch

import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase


class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        def request_cb(response):
            self.finish(response.body)

        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest('http://example.com')
        http_client.fetch(request, request_cb)

class TestHttpService(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestHttpService, self).setUp()
        self.async_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(self.io_loop)
        self.async_patcher = patch('tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient')
        self.mocked_async_client = self.async_patcher.start()

    def get_app(self):
        return application

    def test_async_httpclient(self):
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest('http://example.com')
        response = tornado.httpclient.HTTPResponse(request, 200,
                                buffer=StringIO('test'))
        self.mocked_async_client().fetch.side_effect = lambda x,y: y(response)
        self.async_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), self.stop)
        resp = self.wait()
        self.assertEquals(resp.body, 'test')

application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', TestHandler)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.

Here is my solution in python3.5.

handler.py

```
class VerificationCodeHandler(BaseRequestHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        code_type = self.body_argument.get('code_type', 'register')
        phone_number = self.body_argument.get('phone_number')
        # 发送阿里云短信
        try:
            # This is another API, encapsulate into a coroutine
            send_result = yield ali_sms.ali_send_code_sms(phone_number, code_type, code)
            http_code, send_sms_result = send_result.code, json.loads(send_result.body.decode('utf-8'))
            if int(http_code) == 200:
                if send_sms_result.get('Code').upper() == 'OK':
                    self.success(self.prompt_msg.AUTH_SEND_MSG_SUCCESS)
                    # 缓存数据
                    self.redis.set(key_lasttime, 'send', ex=settings.SMS_INTERVAL)
                    self.redis.set(key_times,
                                   int(is_overrun) + 1 if is_overrun else 1,
                                   ex=settings.SMS_USER_LIMIT)
                    self.redis.set(key_code, code, ex=settings.SMS_EXPIRATION)
                else:
                    self.fail(send_sms_result.get('Message', self.prompt_msg.AUTH_SEND_MSG_ERROR))
            else:
                self.fail(self.prompt_msg.AUTH_SEND_MSG_ERROR_AGAIN)
        except:
            # TODO 系统异常,需要通知管理员
            logger.exception('发送短信失败')
            self.fail(self.prompt_msg.AUTH_SEND_MSG_ERROR_AGAIN)
```

ali_sms.py

```
async def ali_send_code_sms(phone_number, code_type, code):
    url = get_aliyun_sms_url(phone_number, code_type, code)
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    resp = await http_client.fetch(url)
    return resp
```

unittest.mock

```
class VerificationCodeTestCast(BaseHandelrTestCase):

    @mock.patch('common.aliyun.sms.ali_send_code_sms')
    def test_send_sms_fail(self, sms):
        fetch_future = tornado.concurrent.Future()
        fetch_future._result = mock.Mock(body=json_encode({'Code': 'OK'}).encode('utf-8'), code=200)
        fetch_future._done = True
        sms.return_value = fetch_future
        resp = self.fetch('/get_ver_code/', method='POST',
                      body=json_encode({'code_type': 'register',
                                        'phone_number': '17980888160'})
                      )
        result = json_decode(resp.body)
        self.assertEqual(200, resp.code)
        self.assertEqual(400, result.get('code'))
        self.assertEqual(result['msg'], '今日发送短信超限,请明日再试')
```

Note:
When using `ali_send_code_sms` in a handler, don't `from ali_sms import ali_send_code_sms`, `import ali_sms` then `ali_sms.ali_send_code_sms`